# Modal Bootstrap dialog rendered as part of the main page instead of a pop-up

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is using partial views, because of the DevExpress components requirement. When a server condition is true it fires back (via Ajax within MainRibbon.js) and needs to display a modal dialog (residing at the _Layout.cshtml) to the client, but the modal is rendered as part of the main HTML, not as a pop-up. What I am doing wrong here ?

```html
HTML code _Layout.cshtml
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main";
    Page.Title = "BatchPrint main page";
    Page.Verion = "5.0";
}
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts/GridView.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts/MainRibbon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts/RichEdit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts/download.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts/SiteScripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
        .p1 {
            font-family: Trenda, "Lucida Console", serif;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        .newFont * {
            font-family: 'Trenda' "Lucida Console", serif;
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        .gap-10 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 10px;
        }

        .gap-45 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 45px;
        }

        .left {
            left: 0px;
            padding-left: 75px;
            background-color: #DAF7A6;
            color: black;
            width: 85%;
            overflow-x: auto;
            font-family: trenda, sans-serif;
            vertical-align: middle;
            justify-content: center;
            /* Actual code */
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .right {
            right: 0;
            padding-left: 15px;
            width: 15%;
        }

        .split {
            height: 60px;
            position: fixed;
            overflow-x: auto;
            padding-top: 0px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #msgModal {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="gap-10"></div>
    <p class="p1">&nbsp;BatchPrint&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="gap-10"></div>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        #footer {
            bottom: 60px;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView })
    @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView })
    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.RichEdit })
    @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.RichEdit })
    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Icons })
    @Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout })
    @Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout })
</head>
<body>
    <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100vw">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialMainRibbon");}
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align:top; width: 100vw">
        <tr style="vertical-align:top">
            <td style="width: 1%">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 70%">
                <div class="gap-45"></div>
                <div id="container" class="container">
                    @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialGridView");}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 1%">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 27%; vertical-align:top">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialRichEdit");}
            </td>
            <td style="width: 1%">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="split left" id="status_area">
                <div class="centered" color="black" id="message">
                    <h4></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="split right">
                <label id="label_for_bar" for="bar" font-family="Trenda, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" style="display:none">Progress:</label>
                <progress id="bar" value="80" max="100" style="width:90%;display:none"></progress>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    @RenderBody()
    <!-- Message Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="msgModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-target="#msgModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Data breach protection active</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="OK">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <img src=https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg alt="W3Schools.com" style="width:100px;height:100px;" vertical-align="middle" display="inline-block">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <span vertical-align="top">We have detected that a large amount of data was downloaded over a certain amount of time. As a safety precaution we are halting further processing here. If you find that this message is incorrect then contact your administrator.</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
Javascript MainRibbon.js

// Valid callback icons for gridview
var validFunctions = ['View', 'Download', 'View 3D', 'Clear', 'AddLines']

function onCommandExecuted(s, e)
{
    var avrDwnldSpeed         = 3000; // 3 MB/sec average world download speed (2023)
    var minDelayBetweenDwnlds = 1000;
    var waitForDownload = false;  

    ShowMessage("", "normal");
    ShowProgress(false);

    if (e.item.name == 'View')
    {
        GridView.UpdateEdit();
        // Pass the processing to the grid via Ajax
        let typeval = e.item.name;
        let jsonval = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Grid/GridPartial',
            data: JSON.stringify({ type: typeval, json: jsonval }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response)
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    // Show the modal
                    $('#msgModal').modal('show');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you embedded only Bootstrap's JavaScript file - but not the CSS?